# Sobolev type inequalities involving affine metric

Tags: convex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a compact smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with affine metric $h$ and affine volume measure $d\mu_{h}$. If
$$\int_{\mathcal{M}}|\nabla f|^2_{h}d\mu_{h}$$ is small what can I say about $f~$? Sort of Sobolev type inequalities?
Here $|.|_{h}^2$ denotes  the norm with respect to $h$.

Edit:
I can let $f$  be affine invariant also.

Comment: maybe Poincare's inequality can give you some information

Comment: If you don't assume the hypersurface to be convex, then the metric is not necessarily positive definite, In that case, I don't know much.

If the hypersurface is assumed to be convex, then you are just trying to prove a Sobolev inequality for a Riemannian metric on the sphere, where metric happens to come from the affine structure. In that case, the usual way to prove a Sobolev inequality is to prove an isoperimetric inequality. So you want to figure out if the fact that the metric is the affine hypersurface metric implies an isoperimetric inequality.

Comment: What does "$f$ be affine invariant" mean?

Comment: I assume the hypersurface to be convex.

Comment: @ Deane Yang I mean $f(x)=f(Ax)$ for an affine transformation. 

Comment: But what does that mean? In general, if $x$ lies on the hypersurface, $Ax$ does not. And if you allow $f$ to be defined on all of $R^n$, then $f(x) = f(Ax)$ implies that $f$ is constant.

Comment: I mean functions like affine support function.
I wanted to have that integral as an affine invariant quantity.

Comment: I'm still confused by whether you want to get an inequality for an arbitrary function $f$ on the hypersurface or for a specific function $f$ that you have in mind. If it is the latter, then you can take advantage of the specific properties of $f$. For example, if $f$ is defined in terms of the support function and the affine curvature, then the integrand can be written purely in terms of the support function and its derivatives up to order 3. You might want take advantage of this information.

Comment: I am intrested in the general case I was thinking taking special functions like affine invariant ones may still be interesting and make the computation easier and it makes the above integral affine invariant. 

Comment: You still need to figure out what you really mean by "makes the above integral affine invariant". As far as I can tell, it already is for an arbitrary function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the extensive oevre of Yang, Zhang, Lutwak (Deane Yang is active here, and will shed more light, I hope).

Sharp affine Lp Sobolev inequalities
Lutwak, D Yang… - Journal of Differential Geometry, 2002

Comment: Alas, although we do prove affine Sobolev inequalities, I don't offhand have any immediate answer for the question above. I don't see any obvious connection between the integral above and our affine invariant Sobolev "norms". If I find the time, I'll try to think about it more.